# Cassandra - Declare specific field from user-defined type as primary key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I want to declare specific field from user-defined type as primary key.
Assume I have this :

```
CREATE TYPE entity (
  entity_id TEXT,
  entity_type TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE some_object_by_entity_id (
  someId TEXT,
  mytext TEXT,
  entity FROZEN<entity>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((entity.entity_id), transaction_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_id ASC);

...
```

now I want to make somehow the entity_id from entity (which is a user-defined type) to be my primary key, but Cassandra gives me syntax error.
Am I able to do so with any other syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, try to duplicate the entity_id as a simple column of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_object_by_entity_id (
  entity_id TEXT,
  someId TEXT,
  mytext TEXT,
  entity FROZEN<entity>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((entity_id), transaction_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_id ASC);
```

The drawback of this solution is you need to keep in sync your table entity_id and the entity_id value inside the frozen entity manually from the application code.